# How can I stop excel from rounding to .00?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

My Excel formulas are producing answers that only give zeros after the decimal place. For example,

```
=QUOTIENT(10.90,0.0450)
```

gives the answer of `242.00`, it should be `242.22`. How can I keep this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Quotient Function](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/qt/quotient_funct.htm) only gives answers in whole numbers. You can use the simple `=10.90/0.0450` to get decimals in the answer.